# Get element from document.importNode?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a template that I'm cloning in an iteration by document.importNode. What I can not do is to add a class to the cloned element.

```
var t = document.querySelector('#template');
var clone = document.importNode(t.content, true);
document.querySelector('#target').appendChild(clone);
clone.classList.add('glyphicon glyphicon-search'); // error thrown here, classList is undefined
```

What is a cloned node exactly? The console it says it is a #document-fragment. How can I get the created element from the clone without using querySelector and indexing the cloned nodes?

The template looks like this one:

```
<template id="template">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 no"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 no2"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 quantity"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What element are you trying to add the classes to exactly? The template, or an element within it? Can you show your template markup? It would provide for a more illustrative answer

Comment: I've added the template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cloning a `<template>`'s  content will indeed give you a document fragment. This is not a element attached to the DOM, but a lightweight wrapper which contains a set of DOM elements - so it doesn't have properties like `classList`.

You must query the *contents* of the document fragment, *before it's appended to the DOM*, like so:

```js
var t = document.querySelector('#template');
var clone = document.importNode(t.content, true);
// Make any modifications to the clone now
clone.querySelector(".row").classList.add('glyphicon', 'glyphicon-search');
//                          ^^ Note the corrected syntax for classList.add too
document.querySelector('#target').appendChild(clone);
```

```html
<template id="template">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 no">No</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 no2">No2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 quantity">Qty</div>
    </div>
</template>
<div id="target">
    
</div>
```

Results in the following markup:

```
<div id="target">
    <div class="row glyphicon glyphicon-search">
        <div class="col-xs-3 no">No</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 no2">No2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 quantity">Qty</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, clone.querySelector() did the trick. Unfortunately I haven't tried querySelector after classList was not working. +1 for the fixed classList syntax.

Comment: is there a way to return a reference to the instantiated template element after it is appended to the document?

Comment: Down-voted for importing the node and then not actually cloning it in this example. Why are people up-voting code that doesn't work? There is no instance of `Node.cloneNode()` in this post.

Comment: @John `document.importNode` creates a clone of a node from another document already. There is no need to clone it again

Answer (score -1):

i try your code and I think it's beacuse of the tag Template.

If I try the same js code using a div tag instead of template then the classList works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
.red {color:red;}
</style>
<body>

<div id="template">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 no">ddd</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 no2">ddd</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 quantity">dddd</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="target"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var t = document.querySelector('#template');

var clonex = document.importNode(t, true);

document.querySelector('#target').appendChild(clonex);
clonex.classList.add("red");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You may try to add a hidden style to the former template tag, so it will not be show in the page.

Comment: `<div>` and `<template>` tags are fundamentally different in behavior, this is a case of "changing the question to fit an answer."